# Matlab: How to Apply vector to each vector in cell?

Tags: matlab

if `V = [3 11 20 31 40]` and `A=[1 2 3]`, we can do `V(A(:))=[3 11 20]`.

How I can do that if `A` is a cell?

if `A={[1 2 3],[2 5],[3 5]}`, i want to have `{[3 11 20],[11 40],[20 40]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `A` into a matrix (two ways):

```
V = [3 11 20 31 40]
A=[1 2 3]
V(cell2mat(A))
V([A{:}])
```

If `A` is a cell array of indices, use

```
cellfun(@(m) V(m),A,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Comment: but if A={[1 2 3],[2 5],[3 5]} and i want to have {[3 11 20],[11 40],[20 40]}?

Comment: Well that's quite different to what you asked. I will have a look at it.

Comment: @bzak: I don't understand what you are asking for. `A` was your index, now it is something else (because it`s 2 elements or 3 elements). What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: @Daniel: A is cell of vector index.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `V(cell2mat(A))=[3 11 20]` or `V([A{:}])=[3 11 20]`

Answer (score 2):

> but if A={[1 2 3],[2 5],[3 5]} and i want to have {[3 11 20],[11 40],[20 40]}?

I don't think there is a way to properly vectorize this problem, but you can at least use `cellfun` to get it into one line.  It's not going to be especially fast, but at least it's concise... ish.

```
cellfun(@(x) V(x), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: my question was: How I can do that if A is a cell?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant a cell array of doubles in your original phrasing.  I think cellfun solves the problem as you intended it.